# Recover iOS App Source Code Files?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, recovery

I have been developing an iOS App recently, and have been testing it on my phone. However, my files were lost and I didn't have a backup, so I lost the project. The app is still on my iPhone 5 which is jailbroken and has iFile installed. Is there any way I can get my source code at least back?

Comment: It wouldn't be much fun for app developers if that were possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's only compiled files on your phone, and you can't decompile files.

Comment: No, you can't get source code back from your compiled app. Your only hope is file recovery tools. It's possible your files are still on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way you can get back your original source code. An iOS application is compiled into binary and your source code is made executable instructions for processor.

It's possible to obtain some resources (images, media files) if you dig into the compiled app package but your source code is gone; It's not original source code anymore.

There are reverse engineering tools (here's [one](http://hopperapp.com)) to disassemble the binary to view assembly source but it's helpful here only if you know to determine what they do and then you write code that does the same thing.